# Date error in DateProperty() save via ndb

Tags: google-app-engine

Strange results on a saved date in GAE (Python with ndb library).
The inbound string from a web form is %a %m/%d/%y formatted (Fri 3/3/17).
That's parsed with datetime.strptime to get a date value.
When it's saved in a DateProperty() field, the value is consistently the day before, at 16:00:00.000 PST.

```
        postDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.request.get('date-'+
            hashed_id),'%a %m/%d/%y')
        logging.info('postDate as Date: %s',postDate)
        postDateStr = datetime.datetime.strftime(postDate,'%D')
        logging.info('postDateStr: %s',postDateStr)
        thisPost = ScheduledPost(id = postID,
            ...
            postDate = postDate,
            postDateStr = postDateStr
            )
```

log results:

```
    postDate as Date: 2017-03-03 00:00:00
    postDateStr: 03/03/17
```

so far so good, right? but in the Datastore interface, that record shows:

```
    PostDate: 2017-03-02 (16:00:00:000 PST)
    PostDateStr:  03/03/17
```

Oops.

Workstation is in Pacific time - but leaving that aside - date queries seem to confirm that the date is wrong.  Assuming today is 3/3/17 -

```
  today = dt.datetime.now()
  ScheduledPost.query(ScheduledPost.postDate == today).fetch()
```

No record returned.

Saving date as string, and querying on date as string, are feasible workarounds for this project.  Just thought it merited posting - anyone seen this?  Advice?

Comment: update: added a second field defined as  'code' DateTimeProperty() - same erroneous value saved.

Answer (score 0):

The datetime you're generating on appengine is UTC, and it gets stored as that datetime, without timezone information.
When you're viewing it, it's being converted to pacific-time.

The query you're doing is incorrect: you're generating a `datetime`, not a `date`, so the time you're comparing with is going to be different.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize the date viewer was localizing for me.